# Show/Hide span on the same spot

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery to show or hide a span. But I want the `<div>` to appear in the same place as the link I click. The current code actually shows the `<div>` tags on the left side of the screen. Here is the code i am using.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
      return false;
    });
    $(".slidingDiv1").hide();
    $(".show_hide1").show();
    $('.show_hide1').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv1").slideToggle();
      return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Span Tag:

```
<span>
 <a href="#" class="show_hide">Japan</a>
 <span class="slidingDiv">
   <img src="02-1 ImageFiles/01 Japan.JPG" style="width:235px; height:245px;">
   <a href="#" class="show_hide">Close</a>
 </span>
 is made up of islands, regions, prefectures (government districts), cities, and surrounding communities. The main island, Honshu, has thirty-four prefectures making up five regions. The 
 <a class="show_hide1" href="#">Tōhoku Region</a>
 <span class="slidingDiv1">
  <img src="02-1 ImageFiles/02 TohokuRegion.JPG" style="width:217px; height:236px;">
  <a href="#" class="show_hide1">Close</a>
</span>
```

Comment: There are no divs in the code you posted.

Comment: I tried it but its not working. I have several links like these. When I click them, their images appear on the left side of the window and not as the same place as link.

Comment: its not working. I want my span to appear below the link I clicked.

Comment: I know it isn't working, it's your original code in a fiddle for people to use when debugging.

Comment: I didn't get you? you are saying, my code is not understandable ?

Comment: No G-Man, all I'm saying is I put your code in a fiddle and posted it here so people could use it while trying to solve your problem.

Comment: Please check my edited question. I use two or more links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be your HTML part:

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide" style="position: relative;">Japan</a>
<span class="slidingDiv" style="position: absolute; left: 0;">
    <img src="02-1 ImageFiles/01 Japan.JPG" style="width: 235px; height: 245px;" />
    <a href="#" class="show_hide_close">Close</a>
</span>
is made up of islands, regions, prefectures (government districts), cities, and surrounding communities. The main island, Honshu, has thirty-four prefectures making up five regions. The
<a class="show_hide" href="#" style="position: relative;">T&#197;hoku Region</a>
<span class="slidingDiv" style="position: absolute; left: 0;">
    <img src="02-1 ImageFiles/02 TohokuRegion.JPG" style="width: 217px; height: 236px;" />
    <a href="#" class="show_hide_close">Close</a>
</span>
```

and this can be your script part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function () {
        var el = $(this);
        var slidingDiv = el.find("span.slidingDiv");
        if (slidingDiv.length > 0) {
            slidingDiv.slideToggle(function () { el.after(slidingDiv); });
        }
        else {
            slidingDiv = el.next("span.slidingDiv");
            el.append(slidingDiv);
            slidingDiv.slideToggle();
        }
        return false;
    });
    $('.show_hide_close').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent("a.show_hide").click();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Explanation:

- the script will append the span to the anchor on click and will move it back to its original place on closing.
  the reason is that you cannot wrap a block (here is the span) in an anchor tag in the html code, so we will do it at run-time. and we should wrap it because we need to show the span below the anchor tag.
- span containing the img and close button should have absolute position
- anchor which will be clicked should have relative position so browser can calculate the position of the span from the parent anchor, so it will be now below the link
- I generalized anchor and span classes, so you can use it with only one script block
- different class has been assigned to the close button, so clicking it will click the parent anchor

Comment: its still appearing as the same. http://www.mapisms.seas.gwu.edu/2.php - I implemented as you said but its not working. The image still appears at the left side of the page where I want the image to be revealed below the link.

Comment: @G-Man did you replace the HTML code?
you forgot to add "position:relative" to anchor
and "position:absolute" to span.slidingDiv<br/>
I had it explained in Explanation section ;-)

Comment: Oh got it. But the span is hiding the text. How can I resolve that?

Comment: for sure it does!   
that's because you want the span to show below the links..  
also the reader does not need to read the text underneath the span while he/she wants to look at the span.  
i don't understand, please explain more what do you want..!?

Comment: My requirement is that The user must be able to see the text and see the span at the same time. If the user wants to close the image he can do that too. In my previous code, the span was appearing at left of the page but the text moved below the span. I want it like that.

Comment: @G-Man you can't have both at the same time.  
if you want to show a BOX below an element in page, then you should change its position to absolute and that will cover the text underneath for sure.  
if you want the visitor be able to read all of text while viewing the image or BOX, then BOX should be in relative position, which it will be floated in the left side here.

Comment: @G-Man ..  
so what I declared as the solution (position:absolute) is the most standard way to fulfill your need upon positioning a span or div below an element like anchor, and you may leave the choice to visitor to close the span while reading the underneath text is needed.

Comment: there are also other ways to show the BOX or picture, by opening the image in a pop-up window or modal pop-up with drag feature or splitting your page into 2 columns and show the image at the right column when visitor clicks on anchor and maybe other ways...!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18758/discussion-between-mahyar-and-g-man)

Answer (score -1):

Remove the div and Set the span  to **display: block**

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Japan</a>
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Close</a>
<span class="slidingDiv">
    <img src="02-1 ImageFiles/01 Japan.JPG" style="width:235px; height:245px;" />    
</span>

span
{
   display: block;
}​
```

[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3AfUS/3/)

Comment: This is not the solution I am looking for. I want my span to appear below my link that I clicked. But your solution makes the image appear on the left side

Comment: Please check my edited question. I use more than 2 links. I don't want to used div tag but i want to use span tag to avoid newline.

Comment: I used your code but its not working. Checkout this page http://www.mapisms.seas.gwu.edu/2.php

Comment: If thats the case then you need to encase that in one more container and use position: relative property .. Otherwise it is difficult to set its position .. You can set the div to be inline or inline-bloc if you do not want the block effect