# How to SlideToggle below the link (or show/hide below the link)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show/Hide span on the same spot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124300/show-hide-span-on-the-same-spot)

Please check out this webpage that I am designing: http://www.mapisms.seas.gwu.edu/2.php

Here I have two links and when I click each one of them, the span tags appear on the left side of the screen. But i want each of them to appear below their respective links.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    return false;
    });

    $(".slidingDiv1").hide();
    $(".show_hide1").show();

    $('.show_hide1').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv1").slideToggle();
    return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

and the tags are:

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Japan</a><span class="slidingDiv"><img src="02-1 ImageFiles/01 Japan.JPG" style="width:235px; height:245px;" /><a href="#" class="show_hide">Close</a></span> is made up of islands, regions, prefectures (government districts), cities, and surrounding communities. The main island, Honshu, has thirty-four prefectures making up five regions. The <a class="show_hide1" href="#">Tōhoku Region</a><span class="slidingDiv1"><img src="02-1 ImageFiles/02 TohokuRegion.JPG" style="width:217px; height:236px;" /><a href="#" class="show_hide1">Close</a></span>
```

Comment: exact duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124300/show-hide-span-on-the-same-spot/13124400#13124400](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124300/show-hide-span-on-the-same-spot/13124400#13124400)

Comment: looks to appear below link to me on test page using chrome

Comment: @user1479606 I re-posted my question clearly to get exact answers. @ NuclearGhost  I didn't get you.